# How can I bulk import texts (SMS) from a SIM card?

Tags: sms, sim-card, import

How can I bulk import texts (SMS) from a SIM card ?
I'm using a Nexus S with Gingerbread.
The 1by1 import feature (copying the sms to the phone) removes the original sender.

Comment: I don't know if it may help you but I had [similar problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176460/exporting-sms-on-sim-card-to-text-file)