# Exporting SMS on sim card to text file

Tags: sms, backup, sim-card

It seems to me like Android comes with the "veiled" idea that management of SMS that may be present on sim card is not so important (and maybe it's true). Anyway, take me, I have to deal with them at this moment.

Being more precise, I would like to backup all SMS (both received and sent) that are stored in a sim card and I didn't found a fast way to do that.
By this moment I came across several apps that could let me backup/restore SMS that are held on phone but nothing -NOTHING- that deals with the ones on sim card also.

What's worst is that it seems the smartphone I'm dealing with has not ability to copy all the SMS at once, so I should copy them from sim card to phone one by one and then use one of the app I mentioned before... Now, every sim card may contains even 40 SMS and I have at least 4 sim card to backup, that would be really uncomfortable!

So what I ask is: can you please suggest

- an app to save/export SMS on sim card directly to text file (txt, csv, html, xml, ...)
- or a way to copy/move all SMS from sim card to phone AT ONCE (not one by one)

Your help in this would be very appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**
Trust me, by now I tried several apps. Popular ones (like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) or [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdroidapps.smsbackuprestore)) and even less known but sim-card-specific such as [Sim +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jac.simplus) and I couldn't ever get SMS on sim card to be exported. So I became to think it has to do with the device I'm using (I didn't test [Sim Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.robotobia.sim.manager2) for the same reason). Actually, in fact, I managed the situation in another way: *using another smartphone!*

I borrowed a 5 years old Samsung that came with the ability to copy SMS from sim to phone all at once (I guess it's a feature that minor brands devices don't provide)... and I can then be able to use any app to get SMS exported to text.

Now I'm thinking if it's worth keeping this question or not...

Comment: i think this app will help you https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts

Comment: @AniruddhParihar : thank you for trying to help me. I must tell you I won't try that app because it seems to me it requires too much permissions and I don't think it's worth as I wouldn't be surprised if it couldn't solve my problem... Please read my question as I edited.